# Assign a password to a user created without login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to create a user on a SQL Server 2005 database using the "without login" option. In other words, I only want the logon to be for that database.

I've seen in the documentation how to create a user using "without login", but I haven't seen anything with regards to a password.

I don't care if the solution is a description of how to do this Management Studio or via a T-SQL script.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create user YourLoginlessUser without login
go
```

That code creates a *Loginless User*.  When you create a loginless user, it is a user without a password.  It is used to alter the security context for a given securable.

So to answer your question, you have it down how to create a loginless user.  But a loginless user will not have a password, so that isn't part of the user creation.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance about this....  Could you give an example of what you mean by " It is used to alter the security context for a given securable."?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same thing, so I deleted the user from the Database > Security > Users  and executed following query,

```
USE [myDatabaseName]

GO
CREATE USER [myDBUser] WITH PASSWORD = 'password1'
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_myRestrictedDBAccess', N'myDBUser'
```